# RecyclerView.onScrolled() not getting called

Tags: android

My recyclerview.Onscrolled() method is getting called only once.
When I am trying to scroll down, it not getting scrolled and onSCrolled method is not getting called

```
   mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

         boolean loading = true;
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
        {

            if (loading) {
                if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    int visibleItemCount = 6;
                    int totalItemCount = posts.size();
                   int pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        loading = false;

                        Log.v("...", " Reached Last Item");
                        int size = mAdapter.getTodoList().size();
                        mAdapter.getTodoList().clear();
                        mAdapter.setTodoList(getNextItems(mAdapter.getResult(),size));
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(size, mAdapter.getTodoList().size() - 1);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you using RecyclerView internal scroll and not outter ScrollView which contain your RecyclerView?

Comment: I am very new to Android, can you please tell how can I check that as in my layout XML I am just using  a single tag <RecyclerView>

Comment: Add to the question your layout xml and your RecyclerView initialization code please.

Comment: Thanks alot but now it is getting called..dont know how..

Comment: But my problem is still not resolved...I am trying to fetch data from Parse database from a table and add endless scrolling using the data in recycler view...I am unable to understand how to apply pagination on ParseQuery ,,what should be the limit, skip etc..when should I notify the Layout manager..etc...Please help me with some code reference....If you want I can share the code also

Comment: Take a look at Paging library from Android Architecture Components. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/

Comment: @AndreiVinogradov you are a saviour for that scroll view comment 

Comment: [I inherited an android project and just discovered ALL of my recycler views are in nested scroll views..](https://giphy.com/gifs/the-office-no-steve-carell-12XMGIWtrHBl5e/fullscreen)

Comment: An alternate solution for the `onScrolled` issue is mentioned here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695696/5845137)